# Running a script in bash

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have a script in one of my application folders.Usually I just `cd` into that locatin in Unix box and run the script e.g.

`UNIX> cd My\Folder\`

`My\Folder> MyScript`

This prints the required result.

I am not sure how do I do this in Bash script.I have done the following

```
#!/bin/bash
mydir=My\Folder\
cd $mydir
echo $(pwd)
```

This basically puts me in the right folder to run the required script . But I am not sure how to run the script in the code?

Comment: Directory separators are `/`, not \ on *NIX systems.

Comment: Unless you are doing something other than `cd` in the script before triggering it (which appears to be the case from the code snippet above), you might want to provide the absolute path to the script `</path/to/interpreter> /This/is/My/Folder/Myscript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can call `MyScript` (as opposed to `./MyScript`), obviously the current directory (".") is part of your PATH. (Which, by the way, isn't a good idea.)

That means you can call `MyScript` in your script just like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
mydir=My/Folder/
cd $mydir
echo $(pwd)
MyScript
```

As I said, `./MyScript` would be better (not as ambiguous). See Michael Wild's comment about directory separators.

Generally speaking, Bash considers everything that does not resolve to a builtin keyword (like `if`, `while`, `do` etc.) as a call to an executable or script (*) located somewhere in your PATH. It will check each directory in the PATH, in turn, for a so-named executable / script, and execute the first one it finds (which might or might not be the `MyScript` you are intending to run). That's why specifying that you mean the very `MyScript` in **this** directory (`./`) is the better choice.

(*): Unless, of course, there is a function of that name defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
mydir=My/Folder/
cd $mydir
echo $(pwd)
MyScript
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather put the name in quotes. This makes it easier to read and save against mistakes.

```
#!/bin/bash
mydir="My Folder"
cd "$mydir"
echo $(pwd)
./MyScript
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nickname says it all ;-)

When a command is entered at the prompt that doesn't contain a `/`, Bash first checks whether it is a alias or a function. Then it checks whether it is a built-in command, and only then it starts searching on the `PATH`. This is a shell variable that contains a list of directories to search for commands. It appears that in your case `.` (i.e. the current directory) is in the `PATH`, which is generally considered to be a pretty bad idea.

If the command contains a `/`, no look-up in the `PATH` is performed. Instead an exact match is required. If starting with a `/` it is an absolute path, and the file must exist. Otherwise it is a relative path, and the file must exist relative to the current working directory.

So, you have two acceptable options:

1. Put your script in some directory that is on your `PATH`. Alternatively, add the directory containing the script to the `PATH` variable.
2. Use an absolute or relative path to invoke your script.